# Pulling information from one row cursor - Android SQLite

Tags: android, string, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have this issue where I am trying to fill a String[] with stuff, but the way I am doing it is not working. My app so far, takes XML data, parses it, shoves it into a separate tables, and displays the Items in a list. I'm working on the detailed view, and this is where I am stuck. I keep getting a nullpointer exception error because, even though the String[] has the correct number of 'slots' (I've checked this) they are null.

This is the function:

```
public String[] getDetails(String id, int param){

    Cursor cursor = getDetailsCursor(id, param);

    String[] details = new String[cursor.getColumnCount()];
    int itty=0;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
           do{
              details[itty] = cursor.getString(itty);

              itty++;
           }while(cursor.moveToPosition(itty));
        }
        cursor.close();

    return details;

}
```

Before we ask: It is the right cursor, from information that sometimes come through and the ColumnCount, I know it is the right cursor.

I've ask you guys questions before and you seem to know what it is pretty much instantly. This would probably be the last question I have for this little project.

### Update

```
    public String[] getDetails(String id, int param){

    Cursor cursor = getDetailsCursor(id, param);

    String[] details = new String[cursor.getColumnCount()] , names = new String[cursor.getColumnCount()];

    int i=0;

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    names = cursor.getColumnNames();

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    for(i=0;i < names.length;i++){
        details[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(names[i]));
    }

        cursor.close();

    return details;

}
```

This is the code I currently have. I am going to try your solutions and see if they have the same result.

Comment: cursor.getString(itty), here itty is a column but later on you increaase  it as if it were a row number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Cursor` methods `moveTo...` move the row you're dealing with and not the column. Passing an `int` to a call on `getString(...)` defines the column number. You basically need to do something like this...

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    for (int itty = 0; itty < cursor.getColumnCount(); itty++) {
        details[itty] = cursor.getString(itty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

cursor.moveToPosition or cusor.moveToNext iterates over rows. If you want to read all columns from rows please follow below code.

```
public String[] getDetails(String id, int param){
 Cursor cursor = getDetailsCursor(id, param);
 if (cursor!= null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
  int columnCount = cursor.getColumnCount();

// below while loop will execute only once if there is only one row.
```

// While loop not needed if you are sure that there is only one row. This logic can
// can be extended for creating list of String arrays.

```
  do{
    String[] details = new String[columnCount];
    for(int i=0;i<columnCount;i++){
        details[i] = cursor.getString(i);
    }
// Now details array has information of all columns in current row.

  }while(cursor.moveToNext());
 }
 cursor.close();
 return details;
}
```

Comment: No, I think you misunderstood.... There is only one row, with multiple columns... It is variable. I do not need a string from each row, but many strings from one row.

Comment: Ok got it.. Then why you are iterating over cursor rows. You need to iterate over columns. Please check updated solution. Hope It Helps!